# Porting Oracle procedure to PostgreSQL (exception codes from orafce for utl_file module)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, orafce

I am in the middle of a database migration from Oracle to PostgreSQL. We are using [ora2pg](http://ora2pg.darold.net) to make the conversion the plus automatic possible and the [orafce](https://github.com/orafce/orafce) plugin for PostgreSQL for functions compatibility.

We have just started and a lot of work is to be done.

Just now I am with stored procedures (output from ora2pg script) and after resolving the different syntax errors I does not know how to solve the last one.

In particular the problematic code is the following:

```sql
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'******************************** COMPTE RENDU PURGE_DOUBLONS_FS **************************');
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Debut du traitement le          : '||vDateDebut);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*');
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb de lun appairées à plusieurs ZV  : ' || vNbLunMultiZV);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb FS appairée à plusieurs ZV       : ' || vNbUpdateFsMultiZV);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb Liens Lun/FS en suppression logique    : ' || vNbUpdateLunMultiZV);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb Liens FS en suppression logique    : ' || vNbUpdateFsMultiZV);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb Liens FS(ZG mono ZV)en suppression logique    : ' || vNbUpdateLunFSZVseule);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb Liens FS(ZG mono ZV)en suppression logique 2  : ' || vNbUpdateLunFSZVseule2);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb Liens LUN/FS ZV obsolètes             : ' || vNbOldLunZV);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Nb Liens LUN/FS ZG obsolètes             : ' || vNbOldLunZG);
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Temps de traitement de calcul   : ' || OUTILS.time_to_char(tTotal));
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*');
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'*      - Fin du calcul HOST_LUN le       : ' || to_char(clock_timestamp(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
 select utl_file.put_line(vIdLog,'************************** FIN COMPTE RENDU PURGE_DOUBLONS_FS ****************************');
 select utl_file.fclose(vIdLog);
EXCEPTION
 when UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH then
   select Fin_traitement_fichier('Erreur E/S');
   RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'File location or filename was invalid.';
 when UTL_FILE.INVALID_MODE then
   select Fin_traitement_fichier('Erreur E/S');
   RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'The open_mode parameter in FOPEN was invalid.';
 when others then
   select Fin_traitement_fichier(SQLERRM);
   RAISE NOTICE 'ERR005 : ERREUR TRAITEMENT PURGE_DOUBLONS_FS : %', SQLERRM;
   IF cFs%ISOPEN THEN
     CLOSE cFs;
   END IF;
```

The error produced is the following

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UTL_FILE"
LINE 341:    RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'File location or filename was inval...
                     ^
********** Error **********
```

If I use only the *"when others"* part of the exception treatment it works ok, so the problem comes from the constants ***UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH*** and ***UTL_FILE.INVALID_MODE*** that are not recognised by PostgreSQL.

Any idea if how to treat exception codes from orafce for utl_file module?

Comment: select Fin_traitement_fichier('Erreur E/S'); is invalid - you should to use `PERFORM` instead `SELECT`. Syntax `cFs%ISOPEN` is not supported on pg

Comment: Im dealing with exactly same situation here. How can I assign those customed exceptions ? when I use case in SQLERRM i have an syntax error on the case. Can you please explain to me what exactly you did ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLpgSQL doesn't allow to define own exceptions - so Orafce cannot to define `UTL_FILE.*` exceptions. You should to look to orafce [source code](https://github.com/orafce/orafce) [file.c](https://github.com/orafce/orafce/blob/master/file.c) to list of used exceptions:

The code uses macro `CUSTOM_EXCEPTION`

```
#define CUSTOM_EXCEPTION(msg, detail) \
    ereport(ERROR, \
        (errcode(ERRCODE_RAISE_EXCEPTION), \
         errmsg("%s", msg), \
         errdetail("%s", detail)))
```

In this [list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) you can see all PostgreSQL exceptions. So the name of used exception is `raise_exception` and the reason of exception is in `SQLERRM` variable. So your code should to look like:

```
WHEN RAISE_EXCEPTION THEN
  CASE SQLERRM
   WHEN 'UTL_FILE_INVALID_PATH' THEN
     PERFORM ...
   WHEN 'UTL_FILE_INVALID_MODE' THEN
     PERFORM ...
   ELSE 
     PERFORM ...
   END;
```

Comment: Im dealing with exactly same situation here. How can I assign those customed exceptions ? when I use case in SQLERRM i have an syntax error on the case. Can you please explain to me what exactly you did ?

Comment: @Mariel - I don't understand to your question well. PLpgSQL has list of buildin exceptions, that can be specified by long name (string). Any other exceptions should be specified by SQLSTATE - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html