# migrate oracle to Postgresql UTL_FILE EXCEPTIONS

Tags: postgresql, exception, orafce

I have the same situation as described in this post: [Porting Oracle procedure to PostgreSQL (exception codes from orafce for utl_file module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617176/porting-oracle-procedure-to-postgresql-exception-codes-from-orafce-for-utl-file)

I'm migrating from oracle to postgres with ora2pg and I`m trying to correct the syntax of the exception handling that I have for 'utl_file'. Someone commented a solution in the other post but I didn't understand how to properly apply it.

I have the next code :

```
   V_Step := 1;

    FOR Rec_Report IN C_Report LOOP

      V_Counter := V_Counter + 1;

      -- Header
      IF V_Counter = 1 THEN

         -- Open File
        V_File_Type := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(V_Dir_Name, V_File_Name,'w');

        V_Step := 2;

        bl_create_flat_file_pg.open_html(V_File_Type);
         .......
         .......
         .......

          V_Step :=10

EXCEPTION
when UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH then
PERFORM control_reports_pg.send_error_mail('invalid_path 
V_Step'||V_Step,C_Function_Name);
PERFORM UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(V_File_Type);

when UTL_FILE.INVALID_MODE then
PERFORM control_reports_pg.send_error_mail('INVALID_MODE  
 V_Step'||V_Step,C_Function_Name);
     PERFORM  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(V_File_Type);
```

Therefore for every step I have a piece of code like this that handles the exception. I get a syntax error : 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UTL_FILE".

Please help...

Comment: Do you have orafce plugin ---> https://github.com/orafce/orafce, this emulates Oracle-s internal pacakges such as UTL_FILE without that you cannot use UTL_FILE in POSTGRES as it doesn't exist on its own.

Comment: Yes I have orafce plugin. I`m trying to solve the exception handles and not the utl_files. Any idea ?

Comment: If you replace the oracle tag with the orafce tag, then maybe one of the orafce maintainers might jump in if they're watching.

Comment: I replaced it. Waiting for some help :(

Answer (score 0):

I've been writing PL/SQL for quite some time and I've never come across the PERFORM imperative. If this code is to run on an Oracle instance, then I would simply the remove the two "PERFORM" strings.

If this is supposed to run on a POSTGRES instance, then I'd not expect UTL_FILE to exist. If it does exist, then maybe the user running the code has not been granted permissions to execute UTL_FILE.

Comment: I have orafce plugin. I`m trying to solve the exception handles and not the utl_files. Any idea ?